# how to coin toss using python?

Tags: python, probability, spyder, data-science

I'm new to python and i'm doing a probability question on simulate the result of a coin toss. I read the question but I don't understand how to do it. Here's the question:

"Does python have the capability to generate a random number?
Let’s toss a coin 100 times and write the result to a file where the format of the
line is:

```
<int> throw number, <int> coin result {1 for a head and 0 for tails}
```

For example:

```
1, 1
2, 0
3, 1
```

1. Open a file called random.dat and write out the results.
2. Now open the file for reading and read in each line. Extract the result and
   assign it to a list called heads or tails depending on the result { 1 or 0}.

Consider the length of the heads and tails list for different values of the number of coin toss"

Can anyone help me with this part of the question? do I need to simulate the probability using a for loop?

Comment: Check out `random.choice`, it's part of standard library. `random.choice([0, 1])` will return either 0 or 1 with uniform distribution probability

Comment: @Mirac7 So will `random.randint(0, 1)`. No need to create a superfluous list.

Comment: @DeepSpace Given the assignment, superfluous list will not cause performance issues, and `choose either 0 or 1` might be easier to understand than `random int in 0, 1 range`. If one doesn't understand what it does and sees `randint(0, 1)`, one could potentially assume `randint(*args)` is equivalent to `choice(args)`

Comment: @Mirac7 In that case, one should not assume anything and read the docs

Comment: Who needs a loop? `n = 100; enumerate(map(int,f'{random.getrandbits(n):0{n}b}'), 1)` :D
`

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint

numTosses = 100


fileOut = open("data.dat",'w')

for index in range(numTosses):
    fileOut.write(str(index) + "," \
                             + str(randint(0,1)) \
                             + '\n' )

fileOut.close()


fileIn = open("data.dat",'r')

heads = list()
tails = list()

for line in fileIn.readlines():

    fields = line.split(',')

    if fields[1].strip() == '1':
        heads.append(1)
    else:
        tails.append(1)     

print("Number of heads is: " + str(len(heads)))
print("Number of tails is: " + str(len(tails)))

fileIn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I have one better with Speech Recognition you can use it without speech recognition just scroll down

```
import random
from numpy import true_divide
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voices', voices[0].id)

def speak(audio):
    print(f"Computer: {audio}\n")
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    def SpeakText(command):
        engine = pyttsx3.init()
        engine.say(command)
        engine.runAndWait()
        
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source2:
            print("Computer: Listening...")
            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source2, duration=0.2)
            audio2 = r.listen(source2)
            MyText = r.recognize_google(audio2, language="en")
            MyText = MyText.lower()

            print("You:"+MyText)
    except Exception as e:
        speak("Sir, Please Pardon")
        return None
    return MyText

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        query = takeCommand()

        if "toss a coin" in query:
            speak("sir, what times should the coin be flipped")
            toss=int(takeCommand())
            tail=0
            head=0
            for i in range(toss):
                val=random.randint(0,1)
                if(val==0):
                    print("Tails")
                    tail=tail+1
                else:
                    print("Heads")
                    head=head+1
            speak("The total number of tails is {} and head is {} while tossing the coin {} times".format(tail,head,toss))
```

Code without speech recognition

```
toss=int(input("enter number of times you want to flip the coin")
            tail=0
            head=0
            for i in range(toss):
                val=random.randint(0,1)
                if(val==0):
                    print("Tails")
                    tail=tail+1
                else:
                    print("Heads")
                    head=head+1
            print("The total number of tails is {} and head is {} while tossing the coin {} times".format(tail,head,toss))
```